# Trivialization of $T\mathbb S^1$

Tags: differential-geometry

It appears to me that $\mathrm{d}/\mathrm{d}\theta$ is a global frame on $T\mathbb S^1$ (geometrically).

However, since $\mathrm{d}/\mathrm{d}\theta$ is defined as the pointwise pushforward of the standard frame $\mathrm{d}/\mathrm{d}x$ on $T\mathbb R$ via a local parametrization $\theta:\mathbb S^1\to \mathbb R$, it seems that $\mathrm{d}/\mathrm{d}\theta$ is not defined on all of $\mathbb S^1$.

So how can it serve as a frame at all?

Comment: The notions "defined by local constructions" and "globally nonzero" are not necessarily contradictory characteristics of an object. I'm not certain why you mean by "Inherently local." Perhaps if you elaborated, I could give a more reasoned answer.

Comment: i.e. $d/d\theta$ is defined only on the domain of the parametrization $\theta.$ how can it then be a nowhere vanishing section, if it is not defined on the whole circle?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The parameterization $\theta$ is really not defined on $S^1$, but on $S^1$ minus one point (say, $(-1, 0)$). You can also define another function, say $\bar{\theta}$ on $S^1$ except for, say, $(1, 0)$, and have $\theta$ and $\bar{\theta}$ agree on the whole $y > 0$ part of the circle. And at all points in the intersection of the domains, you'll find that $d\theta = d \bar{\theta}$. So you can define a single form, $\phi$, by saying that $\phi = d\theta$ at $(1, 0)$ and $\phi = d\bar{\theta}$ at $(-1, 0)$, and it equals either one at any other point of the circle.

This form $\phi$ is what's typically "called" $d\theta$. Yeah, it's a lousy name. But that's the name that gets used. The form $\phi$ is, after all, the only continuous 1-form that agrees with $d\theta$ at every point at which both are defined, which is almost the whole circle.

The name is particularly odious because it suggests that $\phi$ is the exterior derivative of something, i.e., that it's an exact 1-form, which it is not. In fact, it's a closed-but-not-exact 1-form, hence generates the first deRham cohomology group of the circle.

Comment: I wouldn't say it's a bad name, exactly. It's what you're stuck with if you want to define a section of a bundle that isn't (a priori, anyway) trivial.

Comment: Not true. Mathematicians *could* have all agreed to call it "$\phi$" (or any other name), just as they chose to use the letter "e" to denote a number near $2.718$. There no reason that the name for this particular 1-form has to begin with the letter "d".

Comment: Amazing and explicit answer. Nice discussion about the $d$ being misleading. Bravo!

Comment: Glad you liked it. Credit where due: this is just a rewriting and slight embellishment of what Spivak's *Calculus on Manifolds" says on page 93, and happily takes me back to 1972-73, when I first read it.

Answer (score 1):

A trivialization of $TS^1$ is just a nowhere-vanishing section. Changing the parametrization changes that section, but it's still nonzero, and the resulting bundles are equivalent (and, of course, trivial); it's analogous to choosing a different basis of the fibers locally.

Comment: d/dθ is defined only on the domain of the parametrization θ. how can it then be defined on the whole circle?

Comment: There obviously isn't an embedding $\theta:S^1 \to \mathbb{R}$, but that's not important; define $d\theta$ locally, then patch those definitions together to define $d\theta$ everywhere on $S^1$. The form $d\theta$ is a section of $T^*S^1$ (I'm being lazy here about identifying $TS^1$ and $T^*S^1$); the latter is a perfectly well-defined line bundle, even if it's nontrivial. (It is trivial, in fact, but the point is that $S^1$ is not a single cell.) Compare the definition of the tangent bundle, for example.